# XPath expression meaning

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm new to XPath and want you to consider the following expression, where `n` is an element:

`//n[parent::n and child::n]`

Does the expression in  `[ ]` mean that the parent and child node of `n` must be the same?

Or am I totally wrong? Thank you.

Comment: install xpath checker add on and try all what you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the expression in [ ] mean that the parent and child node of n must be the same?

The correctness of your statement depends on what you mean by "the same". If by "the same", you mean "identical", then the statement is clearly incorrect. A node cannot be the parent and child of something at the same time.

On the other hand, if you intended to write "having the same name", then it's true. The expression

```
//n[parent::n and child::n]
```

means

> Look for all elements with the name `n`, everywhere in the document, but only if their parent element is also called `n` and if they have at least one child element called `n`.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I mean. If you consider `//n[ancestor::n and child::n]` does it mean that "every" ancestor or only the root must have the same name?

Comment: @PatrickWeiß Neither of the two. XPath expressions are implicitly existentially quantified, which means that an expression like `ancestor::n` always means: "there must be at least **one** ancestor with this name". It does not have to be true for all ancestors, and the ancestor with this name is not necessarily the outermost (root) element.

Comment: Ok now I guess I got it. Thanks again.

Comment: Right, so if that XPath were applied against a document with only `n` elements, it would select all elements *except* the root and leaf elements.